# VBA data type mismatch when blank record exists in MS Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have the following vba query that works fine if there are no blank records in a particular field that contains dates. The error occurs when a blank exists in a particular record.

**What am I trying to do?:** extract a count out of my database between a date range. The startdate and enddate are cell references formatted as "MM/DD/YYYY" and the datebase field containing the dates are formatted as Date/Time, "short date".

**query that works if my field column doesnt contain any blanks:**

```
Dim startdate As Date
Dim enddate As Date
strSql = "SELECT Count(*) FROM tablename WHERE datevalue(Date_field_name) >= " & Format(startdate, "\#mm-dd-yyyy\#") & "AND datevalue(Date_field_name) <= " & Format(enddate, "\#mm-dd-yyyy\#")
```

**I tried adding IS NOT NULL and that doesnt work:(**

```
strSql = "SELECT Count(*) FROM tablename WHERE ANOTHER_Field_Name IS NOT NULL AND datevalue(Date_field_name) >= " & Format(startdate, "\#mm-dd-yyyy\#") & "AND datevalue(Date_field_name) <= " & Format(enddate, "\#mm-dd-yyyy\#")
```

help me pls!! This is driving me mad.

**EDIT** The complete code:

```
Public Sub counter()
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strSql As String
Dim strConnection As String
Dim myCounter As Variant
Dim startdate As Date
Dim enddate As Date
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _
    "Data Source=Data.mdb"
strSql = "SELECT Count(*) FROM tablename WHERE datevalue(Date_field_name) >= " & Format(startdate, "\#mm-dd-yyyy\#") & "AND datevalue(Date_field_name) <= " & Format(enddate, "\#mm-dd-yyyy\#")
cn.Open strConnection
'Set rs = cn.Execute(strSql)

While (rs.EOF = False)
If (Not IsNull(rs(Sent_To_Tech_Date).Value)) Then
myCounter = myCounter + 1
End If
rs.MoveNext
Wend
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What data type is your "Date_field_name" field?

Comment: @Newd Date/time short date

Comment: I don't think you need to do the datevalue thing at all then.

Comment: How are you planning to set the startdate and enddate variables?

Comment: I am picking up those values from two cells in excel

Comment: What are they going to look like in the excel sheet?

Comment: I have it formatted at mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: Okay, I have updated my answer with two ways to do that.  The last one is only if you have them in the wrong format for some reason.

Comment: Ok, I will give that a go and ping back. God bless you and your time mate. I have been struggling with this and really appreciate anyone tying to help me!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally see this kind of situation handled with a NZ function so that the field is just never left blank. So something like this:

```
strSql = "SELECT Count(*) FROM tablename WHERE datevalue(Nz(Date_field_name,"01-01-1969")) >= " & Format(startdate, "\#mm-dd-yyyy\#") & "AND datevalue(Nz(Date_field_name,"01-01-1969")) <= " & Format(enddate, "\#mm-dd-yyyy\#")
```

This also goes off of the assumption that you are just showing some stripped down code because you declare you variables then run a query without ever changing those variables to be a date.

The "01-01-1969" date should work for what you are looking for but if not adjust accordingly. Also my freehand SQL isn't amazing so some syntax might be a little off.

Correction on code:

```
strSql = "SELECT Count(*) FROM tablename WHERE datevalue(IIf(IsNull(Date_field_name),"01-01-1969", Date_Field_Name)) >= " & Format(startdate, "\#mm-dd-yyyy\#") & " AND datevalue(IIf(IsNull(Date_field_name),"01-01-1969", Date_Field_Name)) <= " & Format(enddate, "\#mm-dd-yyyy\#")
```

And if this doesn't suit your fancy if you take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp There are other alternative ways to deal with nulls.

Round three, I think the Null idea was a red herring, pretty sure it is a lot of the un-needed formatting and that the "Format" part wasn't actually setting it to a date so it wouldn't do the comparison properly.  Try out:

```
strSql = "SELECT Count(*) FROM tablename WHERE Date_field_name >= #" & startdate & "# AND Date_Field_Name <= #" & enddate & “#”
```

If your enddate and startdate are going to come in a non-date format then use

```
strSql = "SELECT Count(*) FROM tablename WHERE Date_field_name >= #" & Format(startdate,"\#mm-dd-yyyy\#") & "# AND Date_Field_Name <= #" & Format(enddate,"\#mm-dd-yyyy\#") & “#”
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Newd. I get an error undefined function 'Nz' in expression.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot nz is a VBA function, I will update my post with an alternative.

Comment: I get this error when i try your code: Extra ) in query expression 'datevalue(IIf(IsNull(Date_Field_Name), 
'01-­01­-1969', Date_Field_Name))) >= #01­-01­-2015#AND 
datevalue(IIf(IsNull(Date_Field_Name), '01-­01­-1969', 
Date_Field_Name))) <= #01­-31­-2015#'.

Comment: Looks like it only needs )) not ))) free hand coding isn't my forte.

Comment: mate your first solution worked actually. I used ' instead of ". thank you so much!! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

There is most likely a proper way to do this within the query string, but I haven't run across it.  For this type of situation, I do it in two steps:

Instead of running a Count query, I will run a standard SELECT query to return all the records in the date range of interest.
Then I will loop through all the items in the recordset, discarding any that are null, and counting the rest.

```
While (myRecordSet.EOF = False)
  If (Not IsNull(myRecordSet(Date_field_name).Value)) Then
    myCounter = myCounter + 1
  End If
  myRecordSet.MoveNext
Wend
```

This is not the optimal way to do this in my opinion, but I have used it in the past and I know that it works.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Stewbob. I tried your code and getting an error on this line: If (Not IsNull(myRecordSet(Date_field_name).Value)). This is getting highlighted in red.

Comment: @marv, I forgot the `Then` after the If statement.  I edited the post to show that.

Comment: I added my complete code above. i think i'm missing something very simple. getting a with block variable not set :( kindly help

Comment: @marv, You're getting the error because, once again I got sloppy with my code.  You have `rst.MoveNext` and it should be `rs.MoveNext` in your case.  I edited my post (again) to show that you need to use the same `RecordSet` object in the `If` statement and in the `.MoveNext` statement.

Comment: I corrected the rst. to rs and still get the same error :(

Comment: @marv, you have commented out:  'Set rs = cn.Execute(strSql)     Did you mean to do that?  That line is what runs the query and populates the rs object.

Comment: sorry about that, i was a typo. I dont have it commented in my actual code. still getting this annoying data type mismatch error :/

Comment: the current error is "data type mismatch in criteria expression" :(